# How to setFocus on Next button press event in Ionic-vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, ionic-vue

I’m having difficulties trying to change focus from one input to another by pressing the next button in android/ios keyboard since there is no example for the usage of setFocus method.

Maybe somebody here has already achieved this before? Can anyone please show me some example?

What I’ve tried so far:

`Form.vue`

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <form-input
      enterkeyhint="next"
      v-model="email"
      @keyup.enter="changeFocus('password')"
    />

    <form-input
      ref="password"
      v-model="password"
    />
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  // ... some import statements

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      const email = ref("");
      const password = ref("");

      return {
        email,
        password,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      changeFocus(nextFocus: string): void {
        this.$refs[nextFocus].setFocus();
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

`errors`

```js
TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
[vue-cli-service]     80 |     methods: {
[vue-cli-service]     81 |       changeFocus(nextFocus: string): void {
[vue-cli-service]   > 82 |         this.$refs[nextFocus].setFocus();
[vue-cli-service]        |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[vue-cli-service]     83 |       },
[vue-cli-service]     84 |     },
[vue-cli-service]     85 |   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ref template by defining it as property and use inside a event handler :

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <form-input
      enterkeyhint="next"
      @keyup.enter="changeFocus('password')"
    />

    <form-input
      ref="password"
    />
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  // ... some import statements

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() { 
    const password=ref<string>("")
    function changeFocus(nextFocus: string): void {
        password.value.focus()
      }
    return{
      changeFocus, password,email
    }

    },
```

Comment: i see.. but i already defined password ref as this `const password = ref('')` for v-model inside `setup()` method. Should I define again to get focus as you did?

Comment: it threw this error `Object is possibly 'null'.Vetur(2531)`

Comment: still error `Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Comment: what about `ref<HTMLInputElement>(null)`

Comment: didn't work... `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLInputElement'.`

Comment: try it out without parameter `ref<HTMLInputElement>()`